# Open local html with InAppbrowser

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I've been looking for ways to open a html local levels, Local I mean that the html is inside the www folder of the application of `phonegap`, with `inappbrowser`.

```
var about = window.open("About.html", "_blank", "location=yes");
```

This is the line of code with which I intend to do this, but apparently does not work, if someone could help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code that you have written is correct. it is opening page in inappbrowser.

Now the thing is you have to make sure that you call it after device is ready.

Also check you are using 2.x version of cordova framework. and still if you getting issue with the inappbrowser please provide some more information.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var about = window.open("about.html", "_blank", "location=yes");
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Phonegap 3.0.0? I think this is a bug with this Phonegap version.

I have been using this as a workaround (opening an inappbrowser instance):

```
// Image zoom
$('#container').on('tap', '#content.cmscontent img', function() {
    var browser = window.open((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ? 'file:///android_asset/www/' : '') + encodeURI($(this).attr('src')), '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=yes,enableViewportScale=yes,transitionstyle=crossdissolve');
});
```

See I added `(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ? 'file:///android_asset/www/' : '')` as a prefix before the url. Now it detects when you're app is on Android and adds the local URL in front of it.

Comment: thanks for your post, but at the moment I'm developing the project for ios platform is very likely that the project will also develop for android

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, and achieves it work apparently the problem is that there was cleaning the project and for this reason not added the www about.html

But now I have another problem, as I will have already seen pretending to show a about of the application, for which show the ios version and device name. for this I am using the properties of the object name and version device.That for some reason unknown to me but that are not available in the index file, that I decided to pass these attributes to html url about, for example:

```
var about = window.open("About.html?"+device.name+"&"+device.version, "_blank", "location=yes");
```

and about.html handles these variables with:

```
var cadGET = location.search.substr(1,location.search.length);
```

but does not show the html inappbrowser and location bar only shows loading ...

know if the inappbrowser supports pass url parameters?